# How to insert rows and getting an incremental value if I have NOT setup IDENTITY for a column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with a Primary Key ShopId (setted as not UNIQUE).

A script add rows with ShopId as follow (which are Primary KEY)

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
500
501
502
503  
8
9
10
600 -- higher value
400
300
```

When I use an INSERT statement I want to add a new row with ShopId 601 (with auto increment).

I would like to know if it possible to do it automatically at DB level.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Shops
(ShopId int NOT NULL CONSTRAINT PK_Shops_ShopId PRIMARY KEY, 
Name nvarchar(64) NOT NULL, 
LocationId int NOT NULL )
```

Comment: Sorry for typo, I need 601, I have edited my question.

Comment: A primary key is by definition unique. Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: I apologize, maybe I made a mistake the table as not IDENTITY setted up.

Comment: Sorry, edit was queued :P

Comment: Is there any reason not to set this column as IDENTITY?

Comment: Please add a comment with what I should improve when down-voting. Thanks

Comment: Not sure I understand : you just wanna be able to add some primary key values with a script ( running only one time ?), than use the same logic as an IDENTITY column ?

Comment: If you try to roll your own identity you are in for a LONG and painful process. It is so simple if you have only 1 user in your system at a time. But as soon as you add a second user you have to deal with concurrency. This quickly becomes a pain. You will need lots of code to handle this correctly. My advice, don't do it. Recreate your table with an identity and avoid lots of hassles.

Comment: yes the script just run once, after I want logic as an IDENTITY column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your comment, your script must just run once.

So declare your column as `identity`, and for your script, you can use

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT db_name.table_name ON
run the script
SET IDENTITY_INSERT db_name.table_name OFF
```

This allows you do insert your values in an `IDENTITY` column.

After that, the incrementation will start with the highest value +1.

see [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188059.aspx)